# I am trying to os.walk. and create a data frame that goes into excel

Tags: python-3.x

I have successfully made a os.scandir version of this with single directory output, and it is this code:

```
import os, sys, pathlib
import datetime
from stat import *
import pandas as pd
from pandas import ExcelWriter
from pandas import ExcelFile
import numpy as np 

def get_size_format(b, factor=1024, suffix="B"):
    """
    Scale bytes to its proper byte format
    e.g:
        1253656 => '1.20MB'
        1253656678 => '1.17GB'
    """
    for unit in ["", "K", "M", "G", "T", "P", "E", "Z"]:
        if b < factor:
            return f"{b:.2f}{unit}{suffix}"
        b /= factor
    return f"{b:.2f}Y{suffix}"

# List all files in a directory using scandir()
def get_directoy_contents():

    basepath = input("file path")
    df1 = pd.DataFrame([])
    with os.scandir(basepath) as entries:
        for entry in entries:
            info = entry.stat()
            df = pd.DataFrame({'Name':[entry.name],
                            'Path':[entry.path],
                            'Size':[get_size_format(info.st_size)],
                            'created':[datetime.datetime.fromtimestamp(info.st_ctime)],
                            'Modified':[datetime.datetime.fromtimestamp(info.st_ctime)], 
                            'Last Opened':[datetime.datetime.fromtimestamp(info.st_atime)],
                            'File Extension:':[os.path.splitext(entry.name)[1]],
                            'Bytes':[info.st_size]},
                            index = [0])
            df1 = df1.append(df)
            writer = ExcelWriter(r'C:\Users\Andrey\Desktop\Folder Info Scan.xlsx')
            df1.to_excel(writer,'Sheet1',index=False)
            
    writer.save()   

get_directoy_contents()
```

And I get this result:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nnGmW.jpg)

But I am running into issues when trying to use os.walk, here I am trying to build upon the first snippet and get a full directory scan, but the output is still single directory. My goal is to get the file info data for all sub directories and concatenate them. I want the entire data to come out to one new spreadsheet.

```
import os, sys, pathlib
import datetime
from stat import *
import pandas as pd
from pandas import ExcelWriter
from pandas import ExcelFile
import numpy as np 
scanpoint = input('what directory do you want to scan?')

def get_size_format(b, factor=1024, suffix="B"):
    """
    Scale bytes to its proper byte format
    e.g:
        1253656 => '1.20MB'
        1253656678 => '1.17GB'
    """
    for unit in ["", "K", "M", "G", "T", "P", "E", "Z"]:
        if b < factor:
            return f"{b:.2f}{unit}{suffix}"
        b /= factor
    return f"{b:.2f}Y{suffix}"

for root, dirs, files in os.walk(scanpoint):
    df1 = pd.DataFrame([])
    for file in files:
        info = file.stat()
        df = pd.DataFrame({'Name':[file.name],
                        'Path':[file.path],
                        'Size':[get_size_format(info.st_size)],
                        'created':[datetime.datetime.fromtimestamp(info.st_ctime)],
                        'Modified':[datetime.datetime.fromtimestamp(info.st_ctime)], 
                        'Last Opened':[datetime.datetime.fromtimestamp(info.st_atime)],
                        'File Extension:':[os.path.splitext(file.name)[1]],
                        'Bytes':[info.st_size]},
                        index = [0])
    df1 = df1.append(df)
    writer = ExcelWriter(r'C:\Users\Andrey\Desktop\Folder Info Scan.xlsx')
    df1.to_excel(writer,'Sheet1', index=False)             
writer.save()
```

Comment: I would suggest you create a small amount of files and folders and look at what the outputs for `root`, `dirs` and `files` are when you `os.walk(your_test_folder)` ... please update your question with your test file/directory structure and show what you expect to happen.

Comment: Hello, the first code snippet gives me the information from a single directory, I am trying to get the information for all sub directories as well in the second snipped. Thank you!

Comment: It doesn't sow an example of the directory/files and what you are expecting. Hold on though and I think I can answer this.

Comment: Also, this looks like you are creating a DataFrame for each file? It appears that you are overwriting the same file repeatedly. Can you fix your indentations and/or clarify  what specifically you are trying to do?

Comment: fixed indentation, and added an image of how my results look for the single directory, and my goal is to have it continue walking through sub directories and output the information for all files and subdirectories as well

Comment: I put an answer up, but where you are writing to the dataframe and to the excel file seems incorrect to me. Why are you getting a new `write = ExcelWriter()` in each iteration of `os.walk()` ? You should get a writer once outside, then use the `writer` inside the loop, then `save()` after the loop exits.

Answer (score 0):

Here is what I mean about an example (sorry this is on Linux, I don't have a windows computer)

## This is my directory and file structure:

```
[ttucker@zim stackoverflow]$ find /home/ttucker/tmp/stackoverflow/top_directory/
/home/ttucker/tmp/stackoverflow/top_directory/
/home/ttucker/tmp/stackoverflow/top_directory/dir1
/home/ttucker/tmp/stackoverflow/top_directory/dir1/subdir2
/home/ttucker/tmp/stackoverflow/top_directory/dir1/subdir2/file2
/home/ttucker/tmp/stackoverflow/top_directory/dir1/subdir2/file1
/home/ttucker/tmp/stackoverflow/top_directory/dir1/subdir3
/home/ttucker/tmp/stackoverflow/top_directory/dir1/subdir3/file2
/home/ttucker/tmp/stackoverflow/top_directory/dir1/subdir3/file1
/home/ttucker/tmp/stackoverflow/top_directory/dir1/subdir1
/home/ttucker/tmp/stackoverflow/top_directory/dir1/subdir1/file2
/home/ttucker/tmp/stackoverflow/top_directory/dir1/subdir1/file1
/home/ttucker/tmp/stackoverflow/top_directory/dir2
/home/ttucker/tmp/stackoverflow/top_directory/dir2/subdir2
/home/ttucker/tmp/stackoverflow/top_directory/dir2/subdir2/file2
/home/ttucker/tmp/stackoverflow/top_directory/dir2/subdir2/file1
/home/ttucker/tmp/stackoverflow/top_directory/dir2/subdir1
/home/ttucker/tmp/stackoverflow/top_directory/dir2/subdir1/file2
/home/ttucker/tmp/stackoverflow/top_directory/dir2/subdir1/file1
```

You are asking for stats about all files and sub directories inside.

As with any problem, you want to break it down into the small pieces and look at the inputs and outputs. So, lets look at the output of `os.walk()`

Now that we have established what the directory and file structure is, we can write a script to look at what the output of `os.walk()` is on that structure.

## Here is that script:

```
[ttucker@zim stackoverflow]$ cat os.walk.py 
import os
import sys

for root, dirs, files in os.walk(sys.argv[1]):
    print(f"root: {root}, dirs: {dirs}, files: {files}")
```

## Here is the output:

```
[ttucker@zim stackoverflow]$ python os.walk.py /home/ttucker/tmp/stackoverflow/top_directory
root: /home/ttucker/tmp/stackoverflow/top_directory, dirs: ['dir1', 'dir2'], files: []
root: /home/ttucker/tmp/stackoverflow/top_directory/dir1, dirs: ['subdir2', 'subdir3', 'subdir1'], files: []
root: /home/ttucker/tmp/stackoverflow/top_directory/dir1/subdir2, dirs: [], files: ['file2', 'file1']
root: /home/ttucker/tmp/stackoverflow/top_directory/dir1/subdir3, dirs: [], files: ['file2', 'file1']
root: /home/ttucker/tmp/stackoverflow/top_directory/dir1/subdir1, dirs: [], files: ['file2', 'file1']
root: /home/ttucker/tmp/stackoverflow/top_directory/dir2, dirs: ['subdir2', 'subdir1'], files: []
root: /home/ttucker/tmp/stackoverflow/top_directory/dir2/subdir2, dirs: [], files: ['file2', 'file1']
root: /home/ttucker/tmp/stackoverflow/top_directory/dir2/subdir1, dirs: [], files: ['file2', 'file1']
```

From this, we can see that the output of `os.walk()` we can seen that during our iteration, the `root` var seems to be set to each directory. So, we can get all the directory stats by calling `os.stat()` on each `root`. Note: I am calling `os.stat()` and not `root.stat()` because the items returned by `os.walk()` appear to be a tuple of a `(str, [str, str, ...], [str, str, ...])` ...

## So, our new script:

```
[ttucker@zim stackoverflow]$ cat os.walk.py 
import os
import sys

for root, dirs, files in os.walk(sys.argv[1]):
    dir_info = os.stat(root)
    print(f"root: {root}, dir_info: {dir_info}")
```

## And, the output:

```
[ttucker@zim stackoverflow]$ python os.walk.py /home/ttucker/tmp/stackoverflow/top_directory
root: /home/ttucker/tmp/stackoverflow/top_directory, dir_info: os.stat_result(st_mode=16877, st_ino=5385876, st_dev=66309, st_nlink=4, st_uid=1000, st_gid=1000, st_size=4096, st_atime=1606171658, st_mtime=1606171646, st_ctime=1606171646)
root: /home/ttucker/tmp/stackoverflow/top_directory/dir1, dir_info: os.stat_result(st_mode=16877, st_ino=5385877, st_dev=66309, st_nlink=5, st_uid=1000, st_gid=1000, st_size=4096, st_atime=1606171618, st_mtime=1606171610, st_ctime=1606171610)
root: /home/ttucker/tmp/stackoverflow/top_directory/dir1/subdir2, dir_info: os.stat_result(st_mode=16877, st_ino=5385879, st_dev=66309, st_nlink=2, st_uid=1000, st_gid=1000, st_size=4096, st_atime=1606171632, st_mtime=1606171629, st_ctime=1606171629)
root: /home/ttucker/tmp/stackoverflow/top_directory/dir1/subdir3, dir_info: os.stat_result(st_mode=16877, st_ino=5385880, st_dev=66309, st_nlink=2, st_uid=1000, st_gid=1000, st_size=4096, st_atime=1606171632, st_mtime=1606171629, st_ctime=1606171629)
root: /home/ttucker/tmp/stackoverflow/top_directory/dir1/subdir1, dir_info: os.stat_result(st_mode=16877, st_ino=5385878, st_dev=66309, st_nlink=2, st_uid=1000, st_gid=1000, st_size=4096, st_atime=1606171632, st_mtime=1606171629, st_ctime=1606171629)
root: /home/ttucker/tmp/stackoverflow/top_directory/dir2, dir_info: os.stat_result(st_mode=16877, st_ino=5385887, st_dev=66309, st_nlink=4, st_uid=1000, st_gid=1000, st_size=4096, st_atime=1606171658, st_mtime=1606171646, st_ctime=1606171646)
root: /home/ttucker/tmp/stackoverflow/top_directory/dir2/subdir2, dir_info: os.stat_result(st_mode=16877, st_ino=5385889, st_dev=66309, st_nlink=2, st_uid=1000, st_gid=1000, st_size=4096, st_atime=1606171658, st_mtime=1606171656, st_ctime=1606171656)
root: /home/ttucker/tmp/stackoverflow/top_directory/dir2/subdir1, dir_info: os.stat_result(st_mode=16877, st_ino=5385888, st_dev=66309, st_nlink=2, st_uid=1000, st_gid=1000, st_size=4096, st_atime=1606171658, st_mtime=1606171656, st_ctime=1606171656)
```

^ as we can see, this returns the same `os.stat_result` objects that you were looking for. Perfect. Now for the files too:

For this one, we need to loop on the `files` array and do an `os.path.join()` for each path to the `root`

## Here is our script:

```
[ttucker@zim stackoverflow]$ cat os.walk.py 
import os
import sys

for root, dirs, files in os.walk(sys.argv[1]):
    dir_info = os.stat(root)
    print(f"root: {root}, dir_info: {dir_info}")

    for file_name in files:
        file_path = os.path.join(root, file_name)
        file_info = os.stat(file_path)
        print(f"file_path: {file_path}, file_info: {file_info}")
```

## The output, again:

```
[ttucker@zim stackoverflow]$ python os.walk.py /home/ttucker/tmp/stackoverflow/top_directory
root: /home/ttucker/tmp/stackoverflow/top_directory, dir_info: os.stat_result(st_mode=16877, st_ino=5385876, st_dev=66309, st_nlink=4, st_uid=1000, st_gid=1000, st_size=4096, st_atime=1606171658, st_mtime=1606171646, st_ctime=1606171646)
root: /home/ttucker/tmp/stackoverflow/top_directory/dir1, dir_info: os.stat_result(st_mode=16877, st_ino=5385877, st_dev=66309, st_nlink=5, st_uid=1000, st_gid=1000, st_size=4096, st_atime=1606171618, st_mtime=1606171610, st_ctime=1606171610)
root: /home/ttucker/tmp/stackoverflow/top_directory/dir1/subdir2, dir_info: os.stat_result(st_mode=16877, st_ino=5385879, st_dev=66309, st_nlink=2, st_uid=1000, st_gid=1000, st_size=4096, st_atime=1606171632, st_mtime=1606171629, st_ctime=1606171629)
file_path: /home/ttucker/tmp/stackoverflow/top_directory/dir1/subdir2/file2, file_info: os.stat_result(st_mode=33188, st_ino=5385884, st_dev=66309, st_nlink=1, st_uid=1000, st_gid=1000, st_size=0, st_atime=1606171629, st_mtime=1606171629, st_ctime=1606171629)
file_path: /home/ttucker/tmp/stackoverflow/top_directory/dir1/subdir2/file1, file_info: os.stat_result(st_mode=33188, st_ino=5385883, st_dev=66309, st_nlink=1, st_uid=1000, st_gid=1000, st_size=0, st_atime=1606171629, st_mtime=1606171629, st_ctime=1606171629)
root: /home/ttucker/tmp/stackoverflow/top_directory/dir1/subdir3, dir_info: os.stat_result(st_mode=16877, st_ino=5385880, st_dev=66309, st_nlink=2, st_uid=1000, st_gid=1000, st_size=4096, st_atime=1606171632, st_mtime=1606171629, st_ctime=1606171629)
file_path: /home/ttucker/tmp/stackoverflow/top_directory/dir1/subdir3/file2, file_info: os.stat_result(st_mode=33188, st_ino=5385886, st_dev=66309, st_nlink=1, st_uid=1000, st_gid=1000, st_size=0, st_atime=1606171629, st_mtime=1606171629, st_ctime=1606171629)
file_path: /home/ttucker/tmp/stackoverflow/top_directory/dir1/subdir3/file1, file_info: os.stat_result(st_mode=33188, st_ino=5385885, st_dev=66309, st_nlink=1, st_uid=1000, st_gid=1000, st_size=0, st_atime=1606171629, st_mtime=1606171629, st_ctime=1606171629)
root: /home/ttucker/tmp/stackoverflow/top_directory/dir1/subdir1, dir_info: os.stat_result(st_mode=16877, st_ino=5385878, st_dev=66309, st_nlink=2, st_uid=1000, st_gid=1000, st_size=4096, st_atime=1606171632, st_mtime=1606171629, st_ctime=1606171629)
file_path: /home/ttucker/tmp/stackoverflow/top_directory/dir1/subdir1/file2, file_info: os.stat_result(st_mode=33188, st_ino=5385882, st_dev=66309, st_nlink=1, st_uid=1000, st_gid=1000, st_size=0, st_atime=1606171629, st_mtime=1606171629, st_ctime=1606171629)
file_path: /home/ttucker/tmp/stackoverflow/top_directory/dir1/subdir1/file1, file_info: os.stat_result(st_mode=33188, st_ino=5385881, st_dev=66309, st_nlink=1, st_uid=1000, st_gid=1000, st_size=0, st_atime=1606171629, st_mtime=1606171629, st_ctime=1606171629)
root: /home/ttucker/tmp/stackoverflow/top_directory/dir2, dir_info: os.stat_result(st_mode=16877, st_ino=5385887, st_dev=66309, st_nlink=4, st_uid=1000, st_gid=1000, st_size=4096, st_atime=1606171658, st_mtime=1606171646, st_ctime=1606171646)
root: /home/ttucker/tmp/stackoverflow/top_directory/dir2/subdir2, dir_info: os.stat_result(st_mode=16877, st_ino=5385889, st_dev=66309, st_nlink=2, st_uid=1000, st_gid=1000, st_size=4096, st_atime=1606171658, st_mtime=1606171656, st_ctime=1606171656)
file_path: /home/ttucker/tmp/stackoverflow/top_directory/dir2/subdir2/file2, file_info: os.stat_result(st_mode=33188, st_ino=5385893, st_dev=66309, st_nlink=1, st_uid=1000, st_gid=1000, st_size=0, st_atime=1606171656, st_mtime=1606171656, st_ctime=1606171656)
file_path: /home/ttucker/tmp/stackoverflow/top_directory/dir2/subdir2/file1, file_info: os.stat_result(st_mode=33188, st_ino=5385892, st_dev=66309, st_nlink=1, st_uid=1000, st_gid=1000, st_size=0, st_atime=1606171656, st_mtime=1606171656, st_ctime=1606171656)
root: /home/ttucker/tmp/stackoverflow/top_directory/dir2/subdir1, dir_info: os.stat_result(st_mode=16877, st_ino=5385888, st_dev=66309, st_nlink=2, st_uid=1000, st_gid=1000, st_size=4096, st_atime=1606171658, st_mtime=1606171656, st_ctime=1606171656)
file_path: /home/ttucker/tmp/stackoverflow/top_directory/dir2/subdir1/file2, file_info: os.stat_result(st_mode=33188, st_ino=5385891, st_dev=66309, st_nlink=1, st_uid=1000, st_gid=1000, st_size=0, st_atime=1606171656, st_mtime=1606171656, st_ctime=1606171656)
file_path: /home/ttucker/tmp/stackoverflow/top_directory/dir2/subdir1/file1, file_info: os.stat_result(st_mode=33188, st_ino=5385890, st_dev=66309, st_nlink=1, st_uid=1000, st_gid=1000, st_size=0, st_atime=1606171656, st_mtime=1606171656, st_ctime=1606171656)
```

Cool. Now, to verify that we have all of our files, let's check the output against a command we know works, such as the output of the find command:

```
[ttucker@zim stackoverflow]$ python os.walk.py /home/ttucker/tmp/stackoverflow/top_directory | wc -l
18
[ttucker@zim stackoverflow]$ find /home/ttucker/tmp/stackoverflow/top_directory | wc -l
18
```

OK, cool. Since we know that `find` lists all files and directories and the number of lines it returns is 18 and our script outputs 18 lines as well, are answer is probably correct. We could, of course, do a deeper validation ... but I will stop here.

---

Well, I can't, for the life of me, figure out why you would want to put anything inside of an Excel spreadsheet but ... to each their own.

You should be able to figure this out from here. Just remember, break things down into the smallest pieces, put debug/print lines everywhere, and always consult the documentation.

Best of luck!

Answer (score 0):

Thank you everyone for helping, I got it working the way I want to.

Here is how it looks:

```
import os, sys, pathlib, shutil
from stat import *
import pandas as pd
from pandas import ExcelWriter
from pandas import ExcelFile
import numpy as np 

scanpoint = input('what directory do you want to scan?')

df1 = pd.DataFrame([])

for root, dirs, files in os.walk(scanpoint):
    dir_info = os.stat(root)
    print(f"root: {root}, dir_info: {dir_info}")
    for file_name in files:
        file_path = os.path.join(root, file_name)
        df = pd.DataFrame({'Name':[file_name],
                            'Path':[file_path],
                            index = [0])
        df1 = df1.append(df)
writer = ExcelWriter(r'C:\Users\Andrey\Desktop\Folder Info Scan.xlsx')
df1.to_excel(writer,'Sheet1', index=False)             
writer.save()
```